# Python Selenium click on a specific row in a table containing the right data in a column

Tags: python, selenium

So I have a table that can have from 0 to x rows and always have 7 columns.

Something like below.

```
    Type   Price   Store  Weight  For-sale  Stock  Discount
x
x
x
x
x
```

here is how the HTML looks:

```html
<table id="my_table" class="datatable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-width:0px;border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <tr class="row" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('my$table','Select$0')">
        <td>
          <td class="first">Meat</td>
          <td>75</td>
          <td>Adams grocery</td>
          <td align="center">1kg</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>Full</td>
          <td>Yes</td>
          <td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('my$table','Select$1')">
        <td>
          <td class="first">Vegetable</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>Adams grocery</td>
          <td align="center">0.5kg</td>
          <td>No</td>
          <td>Empty</td>
          <td>No</td>
          <td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to click on each row if exists that contains the text "Adams grocery" (which is in column 3) so they open in a separate tab, then give new instructions to all tabs at once. For example: Click button "welcome" on all tabs.
I have a feeling the above might be a little too complicated for me as a beginner... So I thought maybe just click on one of the rows to begin with.

Been thinking about this the whole day, thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need something like this:

Tested to this html:
http://jsfiddle.net/zvhrm6tf/

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait    

td_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#my_table tr td"))
for td in td_list:
    if(td.text == "Adams grocery"):
        td.click()
```

and if you need to target the table row you could do something like this:

```
tr = td.find_element_by_xpath("..")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested your code and it kind of works but for some reason it seems to skip looking in row 1, It just went straight to click on row 2 even though both contains "Adams grocery".

Comment: Ok, did you use the same HTML structure as in my fiddle? If not, please make a fiddle of your HTML file

Comment: Hi don't know what you mean wiith using the same HTML structure as in your fiddle. The HTML is as in my first post.

Comment: Strange, now with only 1 row in the table, it finds and clicks it fine, but with 2 rows it chose to click on the 2nd row instead of the 1st. Why would it do that?

Comment: Try with the html in my fiddle, might be something wrong with your html. jsfiddle.net/zvhrm6tf/1